# htaccess Remove Section From URL But Keep Destination the Same

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, server, url-rewriting

I am wondering how to use `RewriteRule`s in a .htaccess file to rewrite a URL, but keep the destination the same. For example: `https://example.com/123/page1` would go to that site, but the URL would appear as `https://example.com/page1` (where `/123` is missing)

Is this possible?

Just to clarify, `https://example.com/page1` would display `https://example.com/123/page1` without the `/123` appearing in the URL.

.htaccess File:

```
RewriteRule On

## HTTPS check:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

What do I need to add?

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation of your question, please share your htaccess file in your question what you have, thank you.

Comment: Is `123` a static string or it can change to different value for different URLs?

Comment: @anubhava `123` is static, `page1` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert these 2 rules below your existing rule:

```sh
# external redirect from /123/ URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+123/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward to add /123/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^123/ 123%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```